# What is Windows 11 doing in the Maintenance Phase of Modern Standby when it should be sleeping?

Tags: windows, sleep, windows-11, standby

I have a new Windows 11 machine that seems to support Modern Standby fine. Often, though, it seems to keep running when I put it to sleep. I have run `powercfg.exe -SleepStudy` and the report shows the system is stuck in the Screen Off state for hours, 99% of which is in the Maintenance Scheduler. The study output shows no detail of what maintenance is actually being performed or why it doesn't seem to end. I can't find any information on how to understand the Scheduler further. Is there a way to explore this or is only Microsoft privy to its internals?

Comment: Look in Device Manager, Sleep Settings and see if Hybrid Sleep is enabled. Probably.  I turn Hybrid Sleep OFF and Hibernate OFF and just use Suspend (Sleep).